# Rspec - testing rails_admin customization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rails-admin

i've a functional and customized rails admin installation on my app and in order to secure everything is working as it should, i want to do some tests for it

I'm trying to accomplish something like this

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe RailsAdmin::MainController do
  render_views

  let(:admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:admin_user) }

  describe "should manage a dashboard" do

    before :each do
      sign_in admin
    end

    it "should render dashboard" do
      get :dashboard
      response.should be_success
    end
  end
end
```

this was working time ago but suddenly every time run the spec i receive this error

```
Failure/Error: get :dashboard
  ActionController::RoutingError:
    No route matches {:controller=>"rails_admin/main", :action=>"dashboard"}
```

here is a copy of my spec helper
https://gist.github.com/3173172

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that testing this stuff in controller specs (in fact unit tests for controller) is a bad idea. Request spec would be a better place.

You could check my example project: https://github.com/lucassus/locomotive/blob/master/spec/requests/admin/manage_users_spec.rb here you have sample request spec for active_admin user section customization.